# Java: How to add seconds to Timestamp?

Tags: java, timestamp

I fail to add seconds to Java Timestamp.

I have this, but, it gives me the same date:

```
int sec = 600;

java.sql.Timestamp ts_from_ws = new java.sql.Timestamp(retry_date);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(ts_from_ws.getTime());
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND,sec);
java.sql.Timestamp ts_new_date_ws = new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The code you've got works for me. As a short but complete program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long retryDate = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int sec = 600;

        Timestamp original = new Timestamp(retryDate);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(original.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
        Timestamp later = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());

        System.out.println(original);
        System.out.println(later);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2011-11-07 10:27:45.302
2011-11-07 10:37:45.302
```

Note the difference of 10 minutes, i.e. 600 seconds.

Of course you lose the sub-millisecond precision this way, which may well not be ideal - and it goes against what I'm normally use a timestamp for in the first place - but it *does* add the seconds...

Another option would be to just use `Timestamp` directly:

```
Timestamp original = ...;
Timestamp later = new Timestamp(original.getTime() + (sec * 1000L));
later.setNanos(original.getNanos());
```

Comment: @RamarajT: The two calls to `getTime()` are very deliberate. `java.util.Calendar.getTime()` returns a `java.util.Date`, and `java.util.Date.getTime()` returns a `long` (milliseconds since Unix epoch). The `Timestamp` constructor parameter is a `long`.

Comment: Oh, ok, my Bad. I didn't debug it, but I remember the TimeStamp class had a constructor with Date as an argument, so thought this could be typo. But looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 19):

I've always favoured brevity:

```
int sec = 600;

Timestamp later = new Timestamp(retry_date.getTime() + sec * 1000);
```

or if you want relative to "now":

```
Timestamp later = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() + sec * 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

In **java 8**, you can leverage the new `java.time.Instant`. In `java.sql.TimeStamp`, two new method are added from *java 1.8*: `public static Timestamp from(Instant instant)` and `public Instant toInstant()`.

So to add sec, we can convert the `TimeStamp` to Instant and then call `plusSeconds` and then back to TimeStamp:

```
Timestamp ts_from_ws = new Timestamp(retry_date);
Instant next600Sec = ts_from_ws.toInstant().plusSeconds(600);
Timestamp ts_new_date_ws = TimeStamp.from(next600Sec);
```

Or one line:

```
Timestamp ts_new_date_ws = TimeStamp.from(new Timestamp(retry_date).toInstant().plusSeconds(600))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void addTimeBySecondsDemo(Date date,int sec){
    //int sec = 300;
    System.out.println("Given date:"+date);
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
    calender.add(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
    Date changeDate=calender.getTime();
    System.out.println("changeDate ..:"+changeDate);                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Timestamp.from(dto.getTimeModified().toInstant().plusSeconds(600))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer please?