# Timezone parsing issue in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone

How do i parse the following date string in a valid java date? I am having trouble parsing the timezone.

> "2013-10-10 10:43:44 GMT+5"

I am using the following method for parsing the date. It works well when the timezone is like "GMT+05:00" but fails to parse the above string even if i use different combinations of z, Z, X

```
  public static Date convertStringWithTimezoneToDate(String dateString) {
        if (dateString == null) {
            return null;
        }
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz");
        Date convertedDate = null;
        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertedDate;
    }
```

Comment: try converting GMT+5 ==> GMT+5:00. It's not valid format according to this

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

Comment: read this [answer][1] may be it will helpfull for you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date

Comment: please refer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035125/java-how-to-add-seconds-to-timestamp)

Comment: Its also best to use RFC 822 timezones, as the lower case z versions 'can' be locale specific.  Like MEST.

Comment: @orak Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format is non-standard. The time zone must respect the syntax given in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone):

> ```
> GMTOffsetTimeZone:
>          GMT Sign Hours : Minutes
>  Sign: one of
>          + -
>  Hours:
>          Digit
>          Digit Digit
>  Minutes:
>          Digit Digit
>  Digit: one of
>          0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

This code the transform your format into a standard one and construct a Java date object.

```
public static Date convertStringWithTimezoneToDate(String dateString) {
    if (dateString == null) {
        return null;
    }
    dateString += ":00";
    System.out.println(dateString);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
    Date convertedDate = null;
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertedDate;
}
```

P.S.: Only one `z` is needed in the pattern string.